# MongoDB sort string field with an internal order

Tags: mongodb

I have a software written in PHP where I want to make some query and sort results.
I would like to sort the results by the field `firstname`.
But I would like that `firstname` is sorted (ASC sort)  so if I have name: `Mark Albert` it must be before `Beatrix` because my query must consider `Mark Albert` like 'Albert Mark'.
How can I achieve this?

This is my basic query is:

```
db.users.find(
   [
     { $sort : { firstname : 1 } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: i am not sure there is any way to do, but you can do one fix, to add one field, split the firstname using space and exchange the first word at last, look this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LCWNVd-oxfk)

Comment: yes, it can be a solution but it's not always the same rule, you can have an example of three names inside firstname. Another problem is: we have millions of record to update and I would like to know if there is a way to avoid a big update.